# Publish gradle artifact whitout source

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working on an Android library for my company. The repo is private but we wanto ther developer can access the library to use in their app. 
As far as I read, **when publishing an @aar, the source code is published at the same time**. Am I right?

Will publishing to bintray Professional account allow this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched to Bintray Pro Account as Bintray Free plugin did not allow  private source code. I'm now using the official Bintray gradle plugin (`classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'`). This allow me to change the **artifacts** and to not publish the **sourceJar**.

So I have the following **config** for **Bintray** :

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "youreponame" // repo name
        userOrg = 'org'
        name = "name" // Package name
        desc = "desc"
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        publish = true
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    failOnError false
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
}
```

The **@aar** is published, and the **javadocJar** too but **NOT the sourceJar**.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles across this, trying to solve it with maven-publish:

You can tailor the artefacts which are published. It might not be the nicest way to do so, but the following approach works with Gradle 5.6+ :

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.android
                // don't publish source packages
                (getArtifacts() as Set<MavenArtifact>).removeIf { it.classifier == 'sources'}
            }
        }
    }
}
```